# How to authenticate with a bearer token when using Spring Rest Docs

Tags: spring-restdocs

Can I use Spring RestDocs to document APIs when the authorization mode is `bearer`?

A pointer to a simple example would be appreciated, it doesn't seem the be available on the Spring RestDocs pages.

Thanks

Comment: REST Docs isn't involved in making the requests to the API that you're documenting. Exactly how you authenticate with a bearer token will depend on the test client that you're using the exercise the API that you're documenting.

Comment: Okay, so in case I use WebTestClient, I would use the same approach as with my WebClient code.

Comment: Yes, that’s right.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually very simple.

First obtain a bearer-token and encode it so you can use it as a string.
Next add the header to your call, like:
`.header("Authorization", "Bearer " + "your encoded token")`

```
TestClient.put().uri("/v1/some_endpoint/foos")
                    .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + "your encoded token")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .body(BodyInserters.fromValue("{"pay":"load"}))
                    .exchange()
                    .expectStatus().isOk();
```